# Custom control resizes after project build

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

Here is the control at design time. As you can this is how it is supposed to look.

[image]

At runtime....

[image]

And design time again after I run the program and close it.

[image]

It's weird because if I run the program again the textboxes resize correctly at runtime but at design time they shrink.

The only custom code for this is setting the image, which is this:

```
    [Description("The image to appear next to the textbox. Image will be resized to 16x16.")]
    public Image StatusImage
    {
        get { return pictureBox.Image; }
        set { pictureBox.Image = value; }
    }
```

I am handling the resize of the control by setting the textbox Anchor property to Top, Left, Right and the picturebox Dock property is set to right. It all seems to work fine until I run the program. Then the design view is messed up. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code... However I did have a similar problem and found that there was an autoscale property on the control that was set to Font. changed it to None and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: That was it! Do you want to repost that as a reply so I can mark it as answer and you get your credit?

Comment: Done. Glad to help, It's been bugging me for a few hours, I guess it was a struggle for you too :-)

Comment: Yes it was...thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code... However I did have a similar problem and found that there was an autoscale property on the control that was set to Font. changed it to None and it solved the problem for me.